# Multiple sorting for GAE Query

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this query to the GAE datastore:

> SELECT * FROM SimpleEntity WHERE (`__key__` != SimpleEntity("102") AND `__key__`
>   != SimpleEntity("104")) ORDER BY `__key__`, count

Although result is ordered by ascending keys (natural ordering) the count ordering by descending is not followed. The scenario is that the entities keys are maps inverse wit the count, example,  `SimpleEntity("102")` is mapped to `count = 9` and `SimpleEntity("104")` is mapped `count = 7`

This is a very crud example but it shows what I need to do. Just want to make sure that the count ordering will be the final ordering but its not happening.

Here's a visual view of the problem I am trying to fix:

[image]

The expected ordering is that count is **ascending**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY __key__, count`

Your query is ordered by `__key__` first, then `count`. That is the result you are seeing. Since the nature of a `__key__` is to be unique, the `count` field will never be used to sort. You cannot have duplicate keys.

**Edit**
I just read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries?hl=en#Java_Sort_orders

> Note: Because of the way the App Engine Datastore executes queries, if a query specifies inequality filters on a property and sort orders on other properties, the property used in the inequality filters must be ordered before the other properties.

It looks like there is no way to do what you want along with the inequality filters on `__key__`. You will have to do the filtering or sorting outside of your query.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate keys? Isn't this just about sorting? I mean like first order by key then order by count, what do you mean?

Comment: Do you understand how sorting works for SQL? GAE does it the same way. First you sort by `__key__`. If you find 2 or more entries with the same `__key__` then you sort by `count`. `__key__` is unique because it is the identifier of the Entity so it will never sort by `count`. It is coincidental that your `count` is showing up descending. Look at your `key` values. They are ascending, just like you asked with `sortAscending("__key__")`.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is I want to "skip" `__key__`'s like those two, but having a equality operator the code is forced to do sorting by key whereas what I wanted is to sort by count. Simply put, sort by count but skip specific keys

Comment: Have you tried sorting by `count` first then `__key__`? You question does not say anything about being required to sort on `__key__`.